# MVC 4: HttpContext.Current.Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a MVC 4 Application. I need to store an object during the entire Request. It needs to be used in differend objects. My idea was tio store it in the HttpContext.Current.Items. But when i do a refresh of the page, my added object still exists in in the Items collection.

I thought that it would be removed and if i remember correctly, i used this technique in other projects. I am using Visual Studio 2012, IIS Express and MVC 4 (.Net 4.5 Framework).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object for a single controller -> view call, then you can use `ViewBag`. ViewBag is a dynamically-typed class which essentially lets you store whatever you would like in it by simply using the syntax `ViewBag.MyProperty`. You can then retrieve the stored data in the view simply by accessing `@ViewBag.MyProperty`.

As mentioned, ViewBag is good for a single call (it is like TempData). If you want this data to be passed back to the server for use in a subsequent request (which therefore implies that it is used in multiple calls), you will probably want to use Session instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i am actually looking for a raison why the Items collections isn't cleared. The HttpContext is probably the only thing that i can use because i am creating it in an external project that actually doesn't know that it is beeing used in an Asp.net or MVC application.

Comment: How are you setting items in the context?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Items["Key"] = value

Comment: Okay, how is it that the setting code is not called when you refresh the page?

Comment: the setting code is called but i thought that when you refresh your page, that the HttpContext.Current.Items gets cleared. I want to create a custom lifetimemanger per request.

Comment: HttpContext is unique to each call. It is not a durable object... it is created and filled accordingly. You'll need to be more specific about what you would like to create if you want more detailed help.

Comment: I know that it's not a durable object. The problem was that is the HttpContext.Items wasn't cleared. I found the solution. It was my machine config. Don't ask me what is was because i tried a lot of things :-)